# How to make normal and displacement maps only apply to certain areas of model?

Tags: texturing, shaders, image, shader-nodes

So I'm trying to make this old rusty radio and this is where I've gotten so far.  I'm trying to figure out how to apply the rust texture's normal and displacement maps only to the rusty parts of the texture.  As of now it's applied to the entire surface.  Anyone know how to solve this?

[image: model and node setup so far]

Answer (score 0):

One possible way you could do it is use this node setup:

[image]

So the idea is to create a vertex color layer, which you paint manually which represents the rust. Then in the shader editor you use this vertex color information to use the rust, otherwise your "normal" shader.